# what maven repos should idea be pointing to?

Tags: java, maven-2

what are popular repo indices i should configure Idea to use?

i have: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<repository>
    <id>java.net</id>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>jboss</id>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
</repository>
```

But I would suggest that you see what dependencies you need, and then add the repository if needed.

Comment: i can't seem to get hibernate annotations

Comment: what do you try? You can ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends on which artifacts you want to use.**

In addition to the repository you use, we use the following repos at work:

https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public/

http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/

http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/

http://google-maven-repository.googlecode.com/svn/repository/

http://download.java.net/maven/2/

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/

(proxied by a local Nexus OSS repository)